# Should I use lies or lay?

Tags: word-usage

Gun rights advocates claimed that the fault (lies or lay?) with people who have mental health issues.

Comment: The present tense [of this verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf) is _lies_, and the past tense is _lay_. Does the writer intend to talk about where the fault currently lies, or about where the fault lay at some time in the past?

Comment: Thank you John. That's what I thought. I will use lay as I am talking about some time in the past.

Comment: Can you rephrase this as: The Gun rights advocates claim that people who have mental health issues are at fault. This avoids the ambiguity of using "lies" and "lay".

Comment: When answering a question, please answer the question. In this case, the question was clear and admits of a direct answer. That answer should have been given as an answer; suggestions which don't actually answer the question are better as comments (if they have to be given at all).